# SLRequestHandler error using Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to mimic the app as in [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMm5t4APGMM), but using Swift and I am facing a problem constructing the closure as shown in the code snippet below.

```
func twitterTimeline() {
    let account = ACAccountStore()
    let accountType = account.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)

    // take action
    account.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(accountType, options: nil,
        completion: { (granted, error) in
            if (granted) {
                // invoke twitter API
                let arrayOfAccount: NSArray = account.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)

                if (arrayOfAccount.count > 0) {
                    let twitterAccount = arrayOfAccount.lastObject as ACAccount

                    let requestAPI = NSURL.URLWithString("http://api.twitter.com/1.1/atuses/user_timeline.json")
                    var parameters = Dictionary<String, String>()
                    parameters["100"] = "count"
                    parameters["1"] = "include_entities"

                    let posts = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.GET, URL: requestAPI, parameters: parameters)

                    posts.account = twitterAccount

                    // This is the Error Prone Area
                    let handler: SLRequestHandler =  { (response, urlResponse, error) in
                        self.array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data: response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &error) as NSArray
                    }

                    posts.performRequestWithHandler(handler)

                }


            } else {
              // do something
            }
        }
    )
}
```

The error I get is

```
    Cannot convert expression's type '($T1, $T2, $T3) -> $T0' to type '()'
```

I have tried checking and explicitly casting the types with no much help. I believe the error is somewhere else. Could anyone help me with what exactly is the trouble? I am sorry, if this turns out to be a näive question.

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an interesting case of error propagation in the compiler — I'd suggest [filing a bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com) with Apple.

The error message you're getting says that you can't assign a closure (which takes three parameters and returns one value) to something that takes no parameters. What's actually going wrong is that the `handler` closure you're defining takes its `error` input parameter and tries to pass it to `JSONObjectWithData(_:options:error:)`. That's problematic from a language perspective because the error you're getting in is an immutable (optional) reference to one error, and the parameter you're passing it to expects a mutable pointer for it to (potentially) write another error into.

It's also incorrect API usage. The error you receive as a parameter in the closure is a report of an error that happened in whatever procedure calls your closure. You should log this error, present it to the user, or examine it so your app can gracefully fail. The error parameter you pass to `JSONObjectWithData` is a place for you to receive reports of additional errors that occur when decoding JSON from your data — you should be handling this error, too. These are two separate places to receive errors, so you shouldn't be passing one to the other.

If you fix that, you'll find a more helpful compiler message saying that the `data:` label on the first parameter to that function should be omitted. Also, you can use type inference for the `options:` parameter. So, your `handler` definition should look something more like this:

```
let handler: SLRequestHandler =  { (response, urlResponse, error) in
    // check for error and do something about it if need be, then...

    var err: NSError?
    if let jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(response, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSArray {
        self.array = jsonArray
    } else {
        // do something about err
    }
}
```

(You can also probably use a Swift typed array instead of an `NSArray` if you know what to expect from your JSON. But that's another subject for another question. Actually, [several questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+json).)

Comment: Thanks @rickster. It worked! I will dig into it a bit more and will file a bug report with Apple shortly :).

Comment: Hi Nikhil, could you please share the code snippet that worked for you as I am also facing similar problem.